# DecoderFallbackException trouble getting correct character

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-8

Let's say I have a file with this input:

> "Crème donut, $1.00"

If a user uploads the file incorrectly encoded as ANSI and I parse it using TextFieldParser() with UTF8 encoding set to throw an exception on invalid bytes, it will correctly through an exception.  It will report:

> "Unable to translate bytes [E8] at index 321 from specified code page to Unicode."

The property "UnknownBytes" contains the byte array with a single entry of [232].  232 is the decimal equivalent of E8. What's odd is that "è" should really be Byte[2] { 195, 168} I believe.

I would like to report back to the user what character caused the discrepancy.

What is the best way to do this?

If I return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ex.UnknownBytes), it returns the Unicode replacement character instead of "è".  Presumably this is because "232" as a single byte is invalid.

What am I missing? It seems like I have all the information I need to be helpful to the user, but I'm unable to communicate it.

Answer (score 3):

I see the issue.  In my example I was using "è" as a foreign character.  This is \xE8 in ANSI but \xC3\xA8 in UTF8. If I tried to render \xE8 in UTF8, or any Unicode encoding I believe, it wouldn't know what I was asking for since \xE8 isn't a valid hex value for the code point U+00E8.

I ended up using the following code which will work for my circumstances given my regional settings on my servers:

```
catch (DecoderFallbackException ex) 
{
    var ansiEncoding = Encoding.Default;

    var ansiOutput = ansiEncoding.GetString(ex.BytesUnknown);

    throw new PageException("This file contains unexpected characters. The following character was found in the file: " + ansiOutput);
}
```

Comment: Ouch for the downvote. I would think this is helpful to someone trying to sort out the meaning of a byte array returned in an encoding exception. I emphasize that my answer works above in my circumstances because the Encoding.Default in my context is Windows Code Page 1252 and the values that would be uploaded to my platform would most likely come from the same code page and so I can output a recognizable value to the end user. YMMV.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because I feel that you do not deserve that. But your solution is not a solution, it only help being able to debug (see the offending string).